# executing a .sql file in command line

Tags: mysql, command-line

Doing

```
mysql -uroot -p -e source F:\code\mysql\mysql-data\myHfs\test.sql
```

gives : ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'f:\code\mysql\mysql-data\myhfs\test.sql'

But if i go inside the mysql command promt with just the `mysql -uroot -p` and then type in `source F:\code\mysql\mysql-data\myHfs\test.sql` , i get the proper output.

the content of the above file being :

```
use gregs_list;
show tables;
select * from clown_info;
```

**Edit** : doing `mysql -uroot -p < "F:\code\mysql\mysql-data\myHfs\test.sql" -t` seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

`mysql -uroot -p < "F:\code\mysql\mysql-data\myHfs\test.sql"`

Comment: i get `mysql: option '-e' requires an argument `

Comment: Sorry, try again without that argument.

Comment: this works : `mysql -uroot -p < "F:\code\mysql\mysql-data\myHfs\test.sql" -t `

Comment: The `-t` option seems strictly only for display, you could do without it if you didn't need the output.

Comment: true. But I'm trying this to build my sql query from inside sublimetext 2 , and this argument will be passed to the command line.